# Django / Python: Convert Markdown to Secure HTML

Tags: python, django, django-templates, markdown

I'm accepting Markdown and need to convert it to HTML to render securely in Django. Right now I'm accepting the form.cleaned_data and converting it to HTML with:

```
import markdown
html_body = markdown.markdown(body_markdown, safe_mode=True)
html_body = html_body.replace('[HTML_REMOVED]', '')
return html_body
```

In the template, I'm rendering it as :

```
{{ object.content|safe|capfirst }}
```

However if you post:

```
0;url=javascript:alert('hi');" http-equiv="refresh
```

The JS will render so XSS is possible.

Answer (score 3):

django's built in [`safe` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std:templatefilter-safe) means that you are marking that variable as ok to output, i.e. you know that it's contents are safe:

> safe: Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.

Django by [default escapes your template variables:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping)

> By default in Django, every template automatically escapes the output of every variable tag. Specifically, these five characters are escaped ...

but it won't strip the javascript away for you (it will just render it unusable), you need to do that manually with a template tag:

[Strip javascript code before rendering in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444893/strip-javascript-code-before-rendering-in-django-templates)

On the other hand, `safe_mode` on `markdown` strips any HTML in the text with `[HTML REMOVED]` as you've seen.

So removing `safe` should be enough to make it safe,

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed 'safe' from template, however it is still rendering. In the JS, I'm not including script tags just straight "0;url=javascript:alert('hi');" http-equiv="refresh" which is passing through the JS filter.

Comment: where is it rendering? If the HTML is being removed, and there's no `<script>` tags, it just normal string output, so it will always render.

Comment: But where is the javascript contained? Surely if should either be stripped out (if it's an `onclick` piece of javascript within a tag) or otherwise very easy to remove (if it's between `script` tags). If it's just random javascript code it's going to be very difficult to detect